# Need to replace text in a tag- xsl

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Input:

```
<Remarks>Random data## B2B## abc,controls,free text ## B2B## random data</Remarks>
```

The XSL should replace

> "## B2B## abc,controls,free text ## B2B##"

in the `Remarks` tag with

> "value1:abc,value2:controls,value3:free text"

Desired output:

```
<Remarks>Random data,value1:abc,value2:controls,value3:free text,random data</Remarks>
```

Comment: I have tried that,not much helpful :(
Can u provide me sample XSL if any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following XSLT performs the expected replacement:

```
<xsl:template match="Remarks">
  <Remarks><xsl:value-of select="concat(normalize-space(substring-before(text(),'## B2B## abc,controls,free text ## B2B##')),',value1:abc,value2:controls,value3:free text,',normalize-space(substring-after(text(),'## B2B## abc,controls,free text ## B2B##')))" /></Remarks>
</xsl:template>
```

**Output:**

```
<Remarks>Random data,value1:abc,value2:controls,value3:free text,random data</Remarks>
```

Or, to make it more general, use variables for the strings:

```
<xsl:template match="/lines/Remarks">
  <xsl:variable name="str2Replace" select="'## B2B## abc,controls,free text ## B2B##'" />
  <xsl:variable name="replacement" select="',value1:abc,value2:controls,value3:free text,'" />
  <Remarks><xsl:value-of select="concat(normalize-space(substring-before(text(),$str2Replace)),$replacement,normalize-space(substring-after(text(),$str2Replace)))" /></Remarks>
</xsl:template>
```

And even more general:

```
<xsl:template match="/lines/Remarks">
  <xsl:call-template name="strReplace">
    <xsl:with-param name="str2Replace" select="'## B2B## abc,controls,free text ## B2B##'" />
    <xsl:with-param name="replacement" select="',value1:abc,value2:controls,value3:free text,'" />
    <xsl:with-param name="onElement" select="'Remarks'" />
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="strReplace">
  <xsl:param name="str2Replace" />
  <xsl:param name="replacement" />
  <xsl:param name="onElement" />
  <xsl:element name="{$onElement}">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(normalize-space(substring-before(text(),$str2Replace)),$replacement,normalize-space(substring-after(text(),$str2Replace)))" />
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

So you could use different values in the call template.

Comment: and one more help : 3 values which are Inside ## B2B## tags are not known, can you help here as well

Comment: I'm not sure how your comment is meant. I updated my answer with an even more general solution. You could adjust the `call-template` parameters according to your needs. If you'd need something different, I'd recommend creating another new question.

Comment: I have posted another question, I mean the values inside ## B2B## tags are not fixed , they change for each transaction